# InPlace editing of ASP.NET Master Pages with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

Hi I am trying to get the inPlace editing functionality. But this time its in Master page of an ASP.net application. I have a label control (for title of each web page) on master page. And in my content page I want to allow user to edit that title. 
Scenario is that Label should be converted to textbox when user click label. edit and then when textbox will loose focus, it should be converted to updated label. I don't want to change my master page contents. Otherwise may be I can add a hidden textbox on masterpage to replace it with label. But my concern is that Can I do this without editing my master page? I tried to work with JQuery `.replaceWith()` method. But I am new to JQuery and asp.net. Please help me thanks.
I tried stephen's solution but getting object not supported Javascript runtime error. JS Code is given as :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery/jeditable.js" charset="utf-8">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".click").editable("~/AdminArea/Setup/SetupFixedText.aspx", {
         tooltip: "Click to edit...",
         style: "inherit"
     });

     });

</script>
```

And in aspx I have a label first I assigned calss to label but now have placed label in "b"

```
div id = 'lblcontent' 
h3 class="BlueHeading"
b class="click" style="display: inline"
asp:Label  ID="lblContentTitle" runat =  "server"  EnableViewState="False"  
/asp:Label
/b

/h3
/div
```

I removed angle brackets as this editor takign it as html.

Comment: You will need to also reference jQuery on that page if you havent done so already

Comment: Give your asp:Label a CssClass property of "click" and remove the click class from the B tag

Comment: edited my answer below to reflect above comment

Comment: oh and you can leave the angel brackets in your code when you post. thats no big deal

Answer (score 1):

For InPlaceEditing with jQuery, you should check out this plugin...

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Should make things a lot easier

**EDIT Given Posted Code**

Change your aspx page to this:

```
<div id='lblcontent'>  
 <h3 class="BlueHeading"> 
  <b style="display: inline"> 
   <asp:Label  ID="lblContentTitle" runat="server" CssClass="click" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label> 
  </b>  
 </h3> 
</div>
```

Comment: Dont for get to vote/mark as answer if this helped...good luck!

Comment: @stephen776 Hi I am getting error that object does not support property in ASPX page. MY JScript code is given as <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery/jeditable.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".click").editable("~/AdminArea/Setup/SetupFixedText.aspx", {
             tooltip: "Click to edit...",
             style: "inherit"
         });

         });
            
    </script>

Comment: Try posting some of your code as well as specific error information in the original question so we can determine what is causing the problem

Comment: And my HTML code is <div id = 'lblcontent'>
<h3 class="BlueHeading">
<b class="click" style="display: inline"><asp:Label  ID="lblContentTitle" runat = "server"EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label></b>
</h3>
</div>

Comment: sounds like u may not have properly referenced jquery and/or the jeditable plugin on your page

Comment: I don't know how to press enter in this text area characters exceeded that's why :( have broken it into pieces.

Comment: you will need a reference to both jQuery and the plugin on the page

Comment: you should not post long code samples in the comments...edit your original question with the code....indent lines of code 4 spaces to format automatically

Comment: I have refrences to JQuery already as I was able to use JQuery functions. .replacewith() and others. do you want me to post it here?